# Xdebug for php 5.6 and Ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, xdebug, php-5.6

It seems that this command is no longer supported .. does anybody have a replacement for this ?

```
root@0ffa76c2d4e4:/home/# sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-xdebug is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-xdebug' has no installation candidate
```